# changing values in db, why this does not affect the view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a content type, f.e  mycontentype, which has titles, like:

```
Title - library1
another title - library1
yet another title - library1
```

so i went in the db and with a MySQL command, i updated all titles to

```
Title
another title
yet another title
```

My issue here is that in a view, i have as a field, the

Content: mycontenttype

which i have set to the formatter as title link.

This brinks as the title the old title  Title - library1, but when this link is clicked, we go the the node  where the title is shown correctly.

if in the formatter i choose full content, i get again all data updated, including the correct title.

Of course i have cleared all caches, i have run update.php,

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So you manually updated the `title` field in `node` table, and you probably forgot to update `node_revision` as well.

You may also have to run `entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache($nids);` $nids being the affected nodes.

Don't update the database manually, in this situation you could do something like this :

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'mycontentype'));
foreach ($nodes as $nid => &$node) {
  $node->title = preg_replace('/^(.+?)\s+-\slibrary1$/', '$1', $node->title);
  $node->save();
}
```